# Outputting unescaped JSON+LD on GatsbyJS React site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, json-ld

I have a Gatsby site I built using React. I want to include structured data by using JSON+LD. I created a specific component which outputs `<script type="application/ld+json">{JSON.stringify([object])}</script>`, with `object` being a JS object with the structured data:

```
let object = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Game",
  name: post.title,
  ...
};
```

However, the JSON.stringify-ed string I get on the compiled site has the quotes HTML-escaped with `&quot;`:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">[{&quot;@context&quot;:&quot;http://schema.org&quot;,&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;Game&quot; …
```

When I try parsing my site with the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), it shows a parsing error. I understand this is because of the `&quot;`s. ([example URL](https://jocsdetaula.club/jocs/catan/))

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
let object = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Game",
  name: post.title,
  ...
};
const mySchema = JSON.stringify(object);
function makeJSONLD() {
  return (__html: mySchema);
}

return (
  <script type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={makeJSONLD()} />
)
```

dangerouslySetInnerHTML docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

FYI, Google docs seem to indicate that you could put your JSON-LD either in the head or the body of the page HTML - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data. Personally, I don't want to fill my Helmet component with unnecessary logic, but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

I did not exactly solve my issue, but by moving the JSON+LD to inside the React `<Helmet>`, it gets output correctly, so it now validates. I leave this here in case anyone else is having the same issue.